# reactjs – REACT – Set initial data in Formik Form after fetching from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, formik

Call for help - I am trying to handle initial data in formik after fetching from API, the form reading initial values but did not after fetching .
i am using useEffect .
Moreover, i am using document addEventListener to handle input search keydown event, i know it is not best practise in React if any body check code and give advice what's problem in form and how to handle input search ref with state.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, FastField } from 'formik';
import SearchOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/SearchOutlined";
import * as yup from 'yup';
import axios from 'axios';
import "./edit.scss";
import Loading from "../Loading";
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
const validation = yup.object().shape({
    emp_no: yup.number().required(""),
    name: yup.string().required(""),
    project: yup.string().required(""),
    nationality: yup.string().required(""),
    iqama_no: yup.number().required(""),
    room_no: yup.number().required(""),
    zoon_no: yup.number().required(""),
    in_date: yup.date().required(""),
    in_reason: yup.string().required(""),
    out_date: yup.date()
});
const initialValues = {
    emp_no: "",
    name: "",
    project: "",
    nationality: "",
    iqama_no: "",
    room_no: "",
    zoon_no: "",
    in_date: "",
    in_reason: "",
    out_date: "",
};
const EditAlameia = () => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async (event) => {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                setLoading(true);
                await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/alameia/search/edit?q=${query}`).then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    setData(res.data);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    if (err.response) {
                        console.log(err.response.data);
                        console.log(err.response.status);
                    } else if (err.request) {
                        console.log(err.request);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Error', err.message);
                    }
                }).finally(() => setLoading(false));
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener('keydown', fetchData);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', fetchData);
        }
    }, [query]);
    if (loading) {
        return (
            <Loading />
        )
    }
return (
        <div className="searchNew">
            <div className="top">
                <h5 >Edit Data</h5>
                <div className="searchInput">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="بحث"
                        id="search"
                        value={query}
                        onChange={(e) => { setQuery(e.target.value) }}
                    />
                    <SearchOutlinedIcon />
                </div>
            </div>
            {(data !== undefined) ?
            <Formik
                initialValues={data || initialValues}
                validationSchema={validation}
                enableReinitialize
                >
                {formik => {
                    console.log(data)
                    return (
                        <Form encType='multipart/form-data'>
                            <div className="bottom">
                                <div className="right">
                                    <label htmlFor="emp_no" >الرقم الوظيفي</label>
                                    <FastField
                                        type='number'
                                        name='emp_no'
                                        id="emp_no"
                                    />
                                    <label htmlFor="name" >الإسم</label>
                                    <FastField
                                        type='text'
                                        name='name'
                                        id="name"
                                    />
                                    <label htmlFor="project" >المشروع </label>
                                    <FastField
                                        type='text'
                                        name='project'
                                        id="project"
                                    />
                                    <label htmlFor="nationality" >الجنسية </label>
                                    <FastField
                                        type='text'
                                        name='nationality'
                                        id="nationality"
                                    />
                                    <button type='submit' className="btn btn-danger" >Update</button>
                                </div>
                                <div className="left">
                                    <div className="room">
                                        <label htmlFor="room">رقم </label>
                                        <FastField
                                            autoComplete="off"
                                            className="formInput"
                                            type="number" id="room_no" name="room_no" placeholder=""
                                        />
                                        <label htmlFor="zoon">زون </label>
                                        <FastField
                                            className="formInput" type="number" id="zoon_no"
                                            name="zoon_no" placeholder=""
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <label htmlFor="in_date">تاريخ التسكين</label>
                                    <FastField
                                        type='date'
                                        name='in_date'
                                        id="in_date"
                                    />
                                    <label htmlFor="iqama_no" >رقم الإقامة </label>
                                    <FastField
                                        type='number'
                                        name='iqama_no'
                                        id="iqama_no"
                                    />
                                    <label htmlFor="in_reason" >سبب التسكين</label>
                                    <FastField
                                        type='text'
                                        name='in_reason'
                                        id="in_reason"
                                    />
                                    <label htmlFor="out_date" >تاريخ الخروج</label>
                                    <FastField
                                        type='date'
                                        name='out_date'
                                        id="out_date"
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Form>
                    )
                }}
            </Formik>
            :<div style={{fontSize: "14px", color:"crimson"}}>Not available</div>            
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default EditAlameia;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solves your issue, but the main issue I currently see in your component is the fact that you are using `addEventListener()`.

Instead of  listening for an `"keydown"` event and checking for <kbd>Enter</kbd> (eg. `keyCode` `13`), you could place your `<input>` in a `<form>` (which is submitted on <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and add an `onSubmit` event via React.

```css
.spinner {
  /* just to push the spinner away from the search bar */
  margin-top: 1em;

  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: 1s linear infinite spin;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotate(0turn) }
  to   { transform: rotate(1turn) }
}

/* keep the snippet console small */
div.as-console-wrapper { max-height: calc(1em + 9px) }
```

```html
<script type="text/babel">
const { useState } = React;

const SPOOF_DATA = [
  { id: 1, label: "John Doe"    },
  { id: 2, label: "Jane Doe"    },
  { id: 3, label: "foo"         },
  { id: 4, label: "foo bar"     },
  { id: 5, label: "foo bar baz" },
  { id: 6, label: "yo"          },
];

const sleep     = ms    => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const randomInt = limit => Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);

function Loading() {
  return <div className="spinner" />;
}

function App() {
  const [query,     setQuery    ] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data,      setData     ] = useState([]);
  
  async function fetchSearchResults(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      console.log("fetch data using query", JSON.stringify(query));
      // const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/alameia/search/edit?q=${query}`);
      // setData(res.data);
      await sleep(1000 + randomInt(2000));
      setData(SPOOF_DATA.filter(({ label }) => label.includes(query)));
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response) {
        console.log(err.response.data);
        console.log(err.response.status);
      } else if (err.request) {
        console.log(err.request);
      } else {
        console.log('Error', err.message);
      }
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={fetchSearchResults}>
        <input value={query} onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)} />
      </form>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {data.map(({ id, label }) => (
            <li key={id}>{label}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </>    
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(<App />);
</script>

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```